# zsh & python. trying to use python script in zsh prompt, however, cannot

Tags: python, zsh, prompt

Hi I am trying to use python script to show my laptop's battery status on my zsh prompt.
I am following [this](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/#define-a-theme).

I made `batcharge.py` script in my `~/bin/` and I did `chmod 755 batcharge.py` in commad line.

this is batcharge.py script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import math, subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]

o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]

b_max = float(o_max.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())
b_cur = float(o_cur.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())

charge = b_cur / b_max
charge_threshold = int(math.ceil(10 * charge))

# Output

total_slots, slots = 10, []
filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * u'▸'
empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * u'▹'

out = (filled + empty).encode('utf-8')
import sys

color_green = '%{[32m%}'
color_yellow = '%{[1;33m%}'
color_red = '%{[31m%}'
color_reset = '%{[00m%}'
color_out = (
    color_green if len(filled) > 6
    else color_yellow if len(filled) > 4
    else color_red
)

out = color_out + out + color_reset
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

and this is my .zshrc script.

```
BAT_CHARGE=~/bin/batcharge.py
function battery_charge {
    echo `$BAT_CHARGE` 2>/dev/null
}
set_prompt(){
NEWLINE=$'\n'
PROMPT="%F{202}%n%f at %F{136}%m%f in %F{green}%1~%f${NEWLINE}%# "
RPROMPT='$(battery_charge)'
}
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd set_prompt
```

and I restarted my shell, however, it keeps showing
'%                     $(battery_charge)

where did I do wrong?

Comment: If you run `~/bin/batcharge.py` manually, does that work?

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `PROMPT_SUBST` option for command substitutions to be evaluated in a prompt.

(Also, there's no need to define `BAT_CHARGE` or `battery_charge`; just call your Python script directly from the prompt.)

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
set_prompt(){
  NEWLINE=$'\n'
  PROMPT="%F{202}%n%f at %F{136}%m%f in %F{green}%1~%f${NEWLINE}%# "
  RPROMPT='$(~/bin/batcharge.py)'
}
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd set_prompt
```

And even more simply, since you are setting the value of `RPROMPT` each time it is displayed using the `precmd` hook, you don't need an embedded command substitution in the first place. Just set `RPROMPT` directly:

```
set_prompt(){
  NEWLINE=$'\n'
  PROMPT="%F{202}%n%f at %F{136}%m%f in %F{green}%1~%f${NEWLINE}%# "
  RPROMPT=$(~/bin/batcharge.py)
}
autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd set_prompt
```